# Searching through data - not reading last line

Tags: java, database, search, text-files

I have a program which searches through a mini-database I have created in a text file, everything works fine, except the fact that whatever is the very last line in the last line of the data is not recognized and whenever I attempt to search for it, it will fail and I am informed that the data does not exist in the database, although it very clearly does when I look at the txt file.

I managed to get a work-around for this, but adding a fake line at the very end that didn't have data, and something I would use such as "xxxxxxxxxx", and then it was able to read the data on top, which originally was the last line before. The problem with this is, I also have to be able to add data to the function straight from my java program, and it would be extremely tedious to have to first remove that fake line, add my information, then put the fake line in again, so I am trying to figure out why it is not searching the last line of my data.

Here is the code for one of my searches:

```
BufferedReader i = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("Elements.txt"));
String data=i.readLine();
while (data!=null)
    {
        String database[]=data.split(",");
        data=i.readLine();
        if (data!=null)
        {
            for (int x=0;x<data.length(); ++x)
            {
                if (database[0].equalsIgnoreCase(elementName))                                                                                  
                {
                    element=database[0];                                                                                                        
                    symbol=database[1];
                    atomicNumber=database[2];
                    atomicMass=database[3];
                    valence=database[4];

                    found=true;                                                                                                                        
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the data that it is searching through:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCgr1.png

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Please, please, please, put the data into [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or something similar if you don't want it in the question itself. Don't screenshot it. That way we can directly copy/paste instead of having to transcribe.

Comment: output of your code?

Comment: you also miss the first line.. before while loop you already i.readLine(); and in while loop again call i.readLine(); so i think you also miss the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove your `if(data==null)` check after you get your last line. You are getting the next line, then checking if that is valid, then continuing, which is unecessary given your while loop. In essence, you are filtering out the last line (since the next line should be `null`)

Also, you can just get rid of the `for` loop which is completely superfluous because nothing changes between each invocation (you only interact with your `database[]` object and `x` is never used; i.e., you are just doing the same thing `data.length()` times).

Comment: I tried this, but then it gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException on this line:             for (int x=0;x<data.length(); ++x)

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see that. Just eliminate the loop. It does nothing since you no longer interact with the data. (you just overwrite the values over and over again)

Comment: also, delete the `break`

Comment: The reason the loop is there is so it searches through each row of the data, if i remove that it will no longer search and only check the first row of my data, which is not what I want it to do. Do you mean the for loop or the while loop?

Comment: Your `while` loop searches through each row. Your `for` loop iterates an `x` value through your `data` String and then does nothing with the value (in fact, you break out of the loop instantly no matter what)

Comment: Sorry, on closer review, I see that `break` is intended to break the `while`. However, as written it breaks the `for`. You should probably keep it.

Comment: Ah, looks like your right, removing the for loop fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
BufferedReader i = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Elements.txt"));
String data;
while ((data = i.readLine()) != null) {
    String database[] = data.split(",");
    if (database[0].equalsIgnoreCase(elementName)) {
        for (int x = 0; x < data.length(); ++x) {
            element = database[0];
            symbol = database[1];
            atomicNumber = database[2];
            atomicMass = database[3];
            valence = database[4];

            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

1. for reading text files, put readLine into while condition, so you
   only have to write it once and no need for extra null checks and breaks
2. you do not have to compare database[0]
       for each token, so move "if" outside of "for"